# Combining effects with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 different jquery effects i want to apply to a forms radio buttons, on one side I have an hover effect for the buttons, and on the other i have a background color change for the selected radios. Here's the code:

For hover:

```
$(".label_radio").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "silver");
},function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
});
```

For selected item:

```
$("#uno").click(function () {
    $("#cambiar").css("background-image", "url(../wp-content/uploads/blanco2patas.jpg)");
    $("#BU").css("background", "red");
    $("#BT").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#NU").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#NT").css("background", "transparent");
});
$("#dos").click(function () {
    $("#cambiar").css("background-image", "url(../wp-content/uploads/blanco4patas.jpg)");
    $("#BU").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#BT").css("background", "red");
    $("#NU").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#NT").css("background", "transparent");
});
$("#tres").click(function () {
    $("#cambiar").css("background-image", "url(../wp-content/uploads/negro2patas.jpg)");
    $("#BU").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#BT").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#NU").css("background", "red");
    $("#NT").css("background", "transparent");
});
$("#cuatro").click(function () {
    $("#cambiar").css("background-image", "url(../wp-content/uploads/negro4patas.jpg)");
    $("#BU").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#BT").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#NU").css("background", "transparent");
    $("#NT").css("background", "red");
});
```

My problem is, when i try to apply the hover effect, when i get my mouse over the selected element it triggers the hover effect, but when I remove the mouse  it doesn't display the selected effect. It should stay red, but i get transparent element

Comment: Please formulate this "statement" into some kind of a question, as it stands, it is NOT a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of a code smell here.

You are repeating the same functionality over and over instead of using a contextual selector (namely, the `this` keyword)

So instead of uno,does, tres, cuatro - which are both redundant (as you can target a specific element using the `:nth-child` selector) and not semantic - you should use one class for all, and ONE event listener for this class, and find the clicked element by using the `this` keyword.

Something like:

```
$(".myClass").click(function () {

    clicked_el = $(this);

    // then do something with clicked element (e.g. clicked_el.show())

});
```

EDIT: as for your question, you are explicitly telling JQuery to use `transparent` background on `mouseleave` (`hover` is merely a convenience function to combine two related events: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`).

This styling (that is, first the silver `mouseenter` and then the transparent `mouseleave`) **replaces** your `background:red`

If you wish to retain the red selected background you should again consider a different approach, such as adding a class to the selected element with the `addClass()` method (remember the contextual magic of `this`), and defining the CSS rules for that class in your stylesheet. This is also a more *semantic* way as the class name (e.g selected_radio) reflects what you are doing better than just `background:red;`.

But this alone won't solve your issue because you currently use inline styling for the hover effect, and it would still take precedence over the `selected` class by **overriding** it with its crushing *weight*.

Thus, the hover impact should be removed by *removing* the additional styling to get back to the default, and not by stating a *positive* style (and `background:transparent` or even `background:none;` ARE  positive statements), which overrides the default.

So again ask yourself: do I really need JS for the hover effect or is it an overkill? Why not use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-selector?

Comment: didnt know that,i'll try this with my form though it isnt what im llooking for

Comment: it's working with the :hover pseudo-selector, thanks for your help!